# Data not being displayed on clicking the element

Tags: java, sqlite

This is the code where I'm selecting the data

```
public ArrayList<ModelContact> getAllDta(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= getReadableDatabase();       
ArrayList<ModelContact> arraylist=new ArrayList<>();    
   String selectQuery="SELECT *FROM "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME ;  
     Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
```

[This is the logcat]
(1) near "FROMCONTACT_TABLEWHEREID": syntax error in "SELECT *FROMCONTACT_TABLEWHEREID="1""
2023-06-08 23:39:05.498 14868-14868 AndroidRuntime          com.example.contactapp               D  Shutting down VM
2023-06-08 23:39:05.537 14868-14868 AndroidRuntime          com.example.contactapp               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.contactapp, PID: 14868
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactapp/com.example.contactapp.Activity_Contact_details}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMCONTACT_TABLEWHEREID": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT *FROMCONTACT_TABLEWHEREID="1"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3781)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3921)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8170)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMCONTACT_TABLEWHEREID": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT *FROMCONTACT_TABLEWHEREID="1"
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1069)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:673)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1714)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1653)
at com.example.contactapp.Activity_Contact_details.loadDataById(Activity_Contact_details.java:45)
at com.example.contactapp.Activity_Contact_details.onCreate(Activity_Contact_details.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3763)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3921) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8170) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

I am trying to display the contact details but it the app is crashing as soon as I'm clicking on the targeted button.

below is where I'm targeting the contact image element

```
holder.contact_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent =new Intent(context,Activity_Contact_details.class);        intent.putExtra("contactId",id);      
  context.startActivity(intent);        
Toast.makeText(context,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Please edit your question and add any error messages, exceptions or stack trace.

Comment: *String selectQuery="SELECT *FROM "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME ;* Typo there - missing space

Comment: Hi @g00se I don't understand clearly where the typo is

Comment: Missing space between the asterisk and `FROM`

Comment: still not working @g00se

Comment: You can't possibly get the same error now the statement has changed

Comment: @g00se i am getting the same error

Comment: Please show output of `System.out.printf("The value of 'selectQuery' is %s%n", selectQuery);`